# Иерархия объектов в C++

Tags: c++

Помогите создать иерархию объектов, которые содержат информацию о комплектации ПК.

Comment: Рад за вас. Но мы-то тут при чем?

Comment: Ставлю Вам пока плюс за намек на знание русской литературы. Напишите класс "Корпус".

Answer (score 2):

Иерархию классов - так точнее.

Вы знаете из чего состоит ПК?

Рассмотрите какие у вас есть сущности, классифицируйте их на простые и составные, какие операции над ними можно осуществлять, какими характеристиками они обладают.В каком отношении друг к другу они относятся.

У вас тут будут монитор, клавиуатур, мышь, кабеля, корпус, блок питания, материнская плата, процессор, ОЗУ, HDD/SSD, видео карта (ну и что-нибудь ещё что придумаете).

Подумайте над тем что из этого обязательно, что из этого нет (без чего компьютер и так сможет работать).

Какими характеристиками обладают данные сущности?
Например, блок питания имеет такую характеристику как мощность, я для некоторых моделей видеокарт нужен будет блок питания с мощностью не менее чем X Ватт. 
Разъёмы интерфейсы. На материнской плате,например, обязательно должен быть разъём под процессор, и ОЗУ + для жёсткого диска.

Вы можете отдельно описать сущность разъём, отдельно сущность интерфейс, у вас тогда у видео карты будет какой-то определённый интерфейс и вы сможете посмотреть если ли на мат. плате соответствующий разъём.

В этом задании всё ограничено лишь вашей фантазией.

Comment: Вот где нужна литература!.. :-)